# Javascript math operation range number

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to solve issue when i need limit integer to minimum and maximum values. In my case its value can be from 0 to 200 and if you add it should add as overhead. So what i want is:

```
var value = 100;
//value - 100  should be 0
//value - 150 should be 150
//value + 150 should be 50
```

For now i have solution how to correctly limit top (and only if min is 0):

```
(value - 150) % 200
```

I understand that its possible to do it with if statements but i am wondering if its possible to that smarter using custom functions.

Comment: Could you add an example where min would not be zero? The laws of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) may no longer hold then.

Comment: @Bergi well in my case its simple since min is always 0, but example can be limit value from 10 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am wondering if its possible to that smarter using custom functions.

The maths would not necessarily be smarter, but using an extra function would be less to write, more readable and better maintainable. To fix the issue with the negative values, use:

```
function mod200(n) {
    return (n % 200 +200) % 200;
}
```

```
>>> mod200(100 - 100)
0
>>> mod200(100 - 150)
150
>>> mod200(100 + 150)
50
```

Comment: its what i need, and its smart since here is just one line of code ;)

Comment: Though not necessarily efficient :-/ Maybe `n<0 ? n%200+200 : n%200` would've been smarter :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
function bound(value, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(val,min),max);
}
```

So in your case, `bound(value,0,200);`

Comment: -1 OP appears to want modular arithmetic, not clamping. To take the second example, `bound(100 - 150, 0, 200)` should be 150, not 0.

Comment: Yes it will limit to min and max but i need if value goes less then 0 then it should do max - value which goes lover then 0

Comment: so bound(-5,0,200) should return 195